# Sitecore 10 React JSS app to embed into non-Sitecore website

Tags: jss

I did one POC with the help of [this documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--client-side-embedding-jss-applications-in-mvc-sites.html) for embedded JSS app.

In this sample, Sitecore content which embedded app is consuming is in same Sitecore instance for Sitecore MVC site where we need to embed this JSS app.

My requirement is that Sitecore React JSS app in Sitecore 10.2 which having form with few steps need to embed into other non-Sitecore website.

Can you suggest what is best option for it?

Comment: Whether both Sitecore components and non-Sitecore components are present in the same solution?